# Parsing html tags from php array in the response

Tags: php, html, arrays, parsing, tags

Having the next array:

```
$link = 'Link ' . '<a href="https://google.com">Learn more...</a>';
$array = ['1' => 'normal string text', '2' => $link];
return $array;
```

The response would be:

1   "normal string text"

2   "Link, <a href="https://google.com">Learn more..."

The result expected would be that the a tag would get parsed:
Link, [Learn more...](https://google.com)

Tried with different solutions, but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Thanks

Edited: The result should be an array in which one of the entries would be that link already parsed and ready to be used.

Comment: why returning an array instead of echoing it out, `echo $link`

Comment: Take a look at [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument) for parsing HTML with PHP

Comment: The array is the response used to provide more details in this api endpoint. Tried with DOMDocument, did not work

Comment: What you want to get in the result? Can you give an example?

Comment: What API are you even talking about? You have only shown us how you return an array _to somewhere_, but we have no idea where and how you actually create any output from that.

Answer (score 1):

well you'r code is correct but you are returning the array outside a function
you need to add it to a function and call it

ex :

```
  public function printArray(){
  $link = 'Link ' . '<a href="https://google.com">Learn more...</a>';
  $array = ['1' => 'normal string text', '2' => $link];
  return $array;
 }
 
//callback
 
echo printArray();
```

or if you want to pass some params

```
public function printArray($link , $text){
  $link = $link;
  $array = ['1' => $text, '2' => $link];
  return $array;
 }

    //callback 
  $link = 'Link ' . '<a href="https://google.com">Learn more...</a>';
  $text='normal string text';
 
echo printArray($link,$text);
```

or just print it like this:

```
$link = 'Link ' . '<a href="https://google.com">Learn more...</a>';
$array = ['1' => 'normal string text', '2' => $link];

print($array[0]);//output : normal string text 
print($array[1]);//output :  Link Learn more...
```

Comment: The $array in the application would be $response, which it is an array containing more details, cannot print it separately.

Comment: can you specify more plz

Comment: The $array would the response from this API endpoint, which later javascript (vue) would output it in the browser, each item from the array separated.

Comment: i have updated the answer it will be more helpful now

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
$link = 'Link ' . '<a href="https://google.com">Learn more...</a>';
$elements = ['1' => 'normal string text', '2' => $link];


foreach($elements as $key => $element){
    echo "{$key} {$element} <br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will work since I haven't tested it but you could try:

```
<?php
$array->data[] = array(
  'Your text', 
  '<a href="https://google.com"><u>Learn more...</u></a>'
);
echo $array
?>
```

Comment: Same result the a tag does not get parsed.

Comment: Trying to output an array with echo, will always only get you the _text_ `Array`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe try a vardump or a echoprintArray?